# Python 3 corrupted file writing to smb share (Python 2 works)

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, corruption

I've got code for copying files to a network share.  The code works fine (on mac) from python 2.7.17, but gives me a corrupt file with Python 3.7.6.  I don't know if this is a bug, or a change between python2 and python3 that I'm unaware of, but I'm at a loss for how to get my code working.

I'm reading a 300MB file from local filesystem into memory, checking the sha1 of the content, then writing the content to a network share (`mount -t smbfs ...` called from `subprocess.check_output`).

```
def read(path):
    with open(path, "rb") as f:
        return f.read()
def write(content, smbpath, sha1):
    with open(smbpath, "wb") as f:
        if (sha1 == hashlib.sha1(content).hexdigest())
            f.write(content)

localroot = <local path>
smbroot = <remote path>
file = <some file.7z>
content = read(os.path.join(localroot, file)
write(content, os.path.join(smbroot, file), <sha read from local system>)
```

Python says the file SHA values match, but when I compute the sha manually (`shasum smbroot/<file>` from terminal), it gives a different sha.  If I copy the file back to the local filesystem, it differs from the original and produces the same (invalid) SHA as `shasum` produced on the share.

I suspected an issue might be with the network disk, but

- it works fine from python2 and
- copying files manually from the terminal works.

So this seems to be specific to Python3.  Are there known changes or bugs?

Comment: For the same file, compare the `hashlib` SHA value you get from Python 2 and Python 3 with what you're getting from `shasum`. That's were there the difference might be.

Comment: You wish to copy files. Consider using `copyfile()`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile

Comment: @martineau Apologies if I wasn't clear.  I'm fairly sure the problem is that the file isn't being written correctly.  If I copy the file back from the network share manually, `cmp` and `diff` both say the file is different from the original.  The SHA says the files are correct in-memory before the write.